# TestNG could not instantiate class happens randomly

Tags: selenium, testng

Is there any way to get more debugging information?  It doesn't always happen but it seems to almost always happen if I try to immediately rerun tests.   I know it's not a classpath issue b/c the tests will run often.

Answer (score 0):

If you created a class with annotations, then don't use/find any page elements before the first annotation.
Testng will looks for the code to instantiate then only to the methods.
Hope this helps.